# apt-get remove vicious cycle

Tags: apt

I am try to resolve some libboost problems. Eventually i decided it would be easier to remove it cleanly and start from scratch. But when i run `sudo apt-get --purge remove libboost*` i get:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcmis-0.3-3 : Depends: libboost-date-time1.53.0 but it is not going to be installed
 liborcus-0.6-0 : Depends: libboost-system1.53.0 but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libboost-date-time1.53.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

so i run `sudo apt-get -f install` and get

```
Reading database ... 200480 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libboost1.54-dev (from .../libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/quickbook', which is also in package libboost1.53-tools-dev 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so now im stuck in this loop and can't neither uninstall nor install

What shoud i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo dpkg -r libboost1.53-tools-dev`, then you should be able to do the `apt-get -f install`.